# Strange noise from heat pump

Tags: hvac

Does anyone have any idea what this strange noise is in the linked video?

It happens after the heater has been on for a while, and it always seems to happen twice (a few seconds apart).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtQA0HVVUM0

Comment: Go ahead and up vote your answer so it gets closed out in the system. Having an answer may help others with the same noise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HVAC technician I had contacted just got back to me right after I posted this. He says the noise is the compressor going into defrost mode, and it is an expected sound for the quality (builder-grade) of the unit I have.